# get the number row of gridpane Javafx

Tags: javafx

I Have a gridpane and the number of row may be inderterminate.
How add a number row of gridpane ?
Or How add at the last of gridpane ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's really unclear for me what do you want to ask. Do you want to get the number of rows of a `GridPane`? Or would you like to add elements into a specified row? Or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply find the maximum row index from the children of the `GridPane`:

```
GridPane gridPane = ...
```

```
int maxIndex = gridPane.getChildren().stream().mapToInt(n -> {
    Integer row = GridPane.getRowIndex(n);
    Integer rowSpan = GridPane.getRowSpan(n);

    // default values are 0 / 1 respecively
    return (row == null ? 0 : row) + (rowSpan == null ? 0 : rowSpan - 1);
}).max().orElse(-1);

// add nodes after last row
gridPane.addRow(maxIndex+1, node1, node2, ...);
```